# Transform Textfile with CRLF To One Line While Preserving CRLF

Tags: string, text, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
Hello CRLF
Foo CRLF
Bar CRLF
```

I want to transform this to be:

```
Hello\r\nFoo\r\nBar\r\n
```

What is the best way to do this? For reference, I am on a Windows machine.

Comment: Do you just want to convert chars 0A and 0D or do you want all non-printing characters to be represented with escapes?

Comment: @DanielPryden convert chars 0A and 0D.

Comment: What would be an acceptable language to have a solution in? It could be done in Powershell pretty easily but I don't know of a good way to do it in a classic `cmd.exe` shell without other tools. In a Unix or Unix-like environment, `tr` can do this job trivially.